# VBAのループ処理書き方について

Tags: vba

VBAで年間の資金繰り表を作成しています。

更新ボタンを押した際にループ処理で月ごとに値が入力されるようにしたいです。
また、値が入力される式は作成済みなのでループで入力される際にCallで呼び出すようにしたいです。(式の名前：InputCalc)

支出・粗利益のなかの項目は増えることがあります。
`i` では支出と粗利益を区別するループ、`j` ではCallで値を入力していくループで構成を考えています。
コードの組み方がわからないので教えていただきたいです…

```
Sub Button1_Click()

With Sheets("HOME")

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

For i = 7 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

End With

End Sub
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/275964

Answer (score 1):

「支出」と「粗利益」以外も、「純利益」とかの項目が増える予定があるのですか？
もしいらないとすると、iのループは2回でよいということになりますよね。
もしいるとすると、iのループ値を求めるために
A列7行目移行を最終行までたどっていって、タイトル文字がある数をカウントして、iのループのカウント数を求めます。

そのループの内部で、B列7行目から下に文字の有無を探して、なくなるまでの個数をもとめて
jのループ数を求めます。

そんなふうにしていくとよいと思いますよ。

Comment: 書き方がわかりづらくてすみません、支出の中の通信費、交際費などそういった細かい項目が増える予定です。

Comment: 支出の中の項目の増減はわかりますよ。
ループ数を求めなければいけないので、for ではなく while を使って、B7から下にセルをたどっていき、B14が空白だ、というのを求めて、ループ数は6だ、というのを求めるのです。